# Am I understanding this IR spectrum correctly?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

Is it safe to say that this IR spectrum belongs to a carboxylic acid because of the 3100-2700 stretch indicating OH group, and the sharp peak at 1728 showing a carbonyl group?

Comment: @ M. Farooq: The IR is not a spectrum of carboxylic acid derivative. It is just a carbonyl compound. I'd like to let OP to express their thoughts before giving any hint.

Comment: @Mohamed:  Don't link to images outside of ChemSE, but embed them (e.g., as a .png file).  This keeps the illustration accessible even if the link to a third-party is invalidated (e.g., change of the address) and allows the users of ChemSE to connect quickly your question to the spectrum in question.